# Using Internet without being spied by my provider

Tags: vpn, privacy

I have read that Internet access providers can see/log requests sent from my computer even if I use a VPN.

Is this true? What is the best solution to surf on the Internet without being "spied" by my provider?

Comment: It depends on how you're using the VPN. If at some point along the line, the traffic is unencrypted, then, yes, it can be intercepted. Note also that anyone may be able to do traffic analysis on you based on where your packets are going|coming from, how often, etc. You can use TOR to defeat this, though in my experience, TOR sacrifices speed for the sake of privacy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell:

VPN service (such as HMA) works in such a way that it encrypts all the network traffic originating from your machine (using its client software), and sends it to a VPN server, where it's being decrypted, and propagated further, per your "web requests". So, VPN server becomes the point where your traffic is "exposed", so to speak. Considering the previous, **ISP that hosts the server** can track/log that traffic, but the only thing they know is that it comes from that server. VPN service provider knows who you are, since it usually logs activities from all its clients (per VPN server), namely virtual private IPs (that are usually dynamic), and real remote IPs, that is, the IPs from clients' ISPs (again, dynamic in most cases).

If our question was wheter or not your ISP can see your traffic through VPN, the answer is **no** (except in the case it cracks the VPN tunnel, which is outside of the scope of this subject).
If your question was whether or not some other ISP can see your traffic, the answer is **yes**.

The bottom line is - it's not easy to track someone through VPN, but if needed, and with sufficient amount of log details, it is doable.

Comment: So, you mean that my ISP won't see the request (through HTTP) ?

Comment: If all your traffic is redirected to go through the VPN tunnel, which is the case with most VPN service providers, your ISP won't see your particular HTTP request, because it's wrapped and stored inside the VPN TCP/UDP packets. So, they can only see those data packets, but since their payload is encrypted, it won't mean anything to them. Your original request actually resides right within the encrypted content.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into using [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) however this will also affect what you can do online as running any plugins such as Flash player etc can compromise your anonymity.

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP will always be able to glean something from your traffic.

Here's some things an ISP can "spy on" specifically and the best you can do to mitigate them:

**1. Content of communications** - ISPs can view and log the contents of your communication between you and a remote server.  Using encrypted versions of protocols will ensure your ISP only sees ciphertext, the typical case being SSL used with HTTPS.  **Always verify the SSL certificate of the remote server** if you are really paranoid about this.  An ISP or other intermediary can place themselves in the middle between you and a remote server, even if SSL is used, but they cannot spoof the certificate presented by the server.

**2. The IP of the remote system you are trying to communicate with** - ISPs can log the destination IP of any packets you have them transit on your behalf.  So, even though you have your sessions encrypted with remote servers, they will still know you are communicating with such-and-such IP.  This is why **a VPN service is helpful**, as then all the ISP will see is that you are communicating with the VPN provider.  Of course, the VPN is pretty much in this situation another ISP and you are trusting it, and #1 and #2 here still apply.  **Tor** is also a great way to hide your destination IP from your ISP, and also your IP from whatever you are trying to communicate with.  But, your ISP will still know you are communicating via Tor as your initial hop must be to a Tor bridge with a known IP address associated with Tor.

**2a. DNS** - Many ISPs provide DNS servers.  Each time you visit a website, a DNS lookup occurs.  This reveals what site you were trying to visit.  It's possible that your ISP could be logging this, even if the actual conversation between you and the server the DNS resolves to is completely encrypted.  Any DNS provider, such as Google or OpenDNS, can also log queries.  Also, DNS itself is almost always unencrypted.  Tor supports DNS lookups over its IP-obfuscating "onion network."  If you are using Tor, but not making sure your DNS also goes through Tor, the domain names of the sites you are visiting are visible to your current DNS servers and easily traceable to you.

**3. When and how much data your communications contain** - ISPs can log the times and amount of data of each packet transmitted.  However, though this is getting into advanced territory, it may be possible to form conclusions about what you are doing giving the times and amount of data you transmit, even if it is completely encrypted and only sent to a VPN provider.  The truly paranoid or hardcore would try not to schedule things online on a peroidic, predictable basis.

Comment: Your point 1 is not valid (and kind of paints your entire response, which is otherwise quite good in a bad light).  When using a VPN means that the information sent through the tunnel is already encrypted so your ISP can't sniff on it [ although this can be sniffed once broken out the tunnel ]